# WebDriver Portable Firefox c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried to load Portable Firefox

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
var binary = new FirefoxBinary(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+ @"\FirefoxPortable64\FirefoxPortable.exe");

var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

But i get error `Unable to find a matching set of capabilities` in line `var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);`

can u help me pls ?

And in line `var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);` i have warning:

> FirefoxDriver should not be constructed with a FirefoxBinary object. Use FirefoxOptions instead. This constructor will be removed in a future release.

how i can rewrite the code ?

UPD:
I rewrite code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = profile;
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\FirefoxPortable64\FirefoxPortable.exe";
var driver = new FirefoxDriver( options);
```

But it doesnt work, again have error `Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Answer (score 0):

Solution ;

```
 options.BrowserExecutableLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\FirefoxPortable32\App\Firefox\firefox.exe";
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to add a description of what the code does and how it answers the question.